# Retrieve data between two certain dates from access database using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am looking for a specific query in C# for access database to get data between two dates although start and end dates are not available in database.

This is my code:

```
sql = "Select Working_Date From Attendance
   where Format(Working_Date,'Short date') BETWEEN#" 
   + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date 
   + "#AND#" 
   + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "#";
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "although start and end dates are not available in database" or what the result of your existing code is. I'd strongly advise a) not using strings where you don't need to; b) using parameterized SQL though.

Comment: what is the expected result? what is in your database? what goes wrong?

Comment: one thing worth to point reading your query - do you have datetimepicker2 as start date and datepicker1 as enddate? Are you sure, that they are not in wrong order?

Comment: you can put space at `# AND #` like this. this will also create problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for quick response,

1. I have a access database with **Working_Date** Field having data Type **Date/time** for daily attendance of Employee.
2. I want to see the presence of employee between two specific dates(Monthly cycle- e.g. 25-Jan-2015 To 25-Feb-2015)
3. When I execute following query for first month like (01/01/2015 & 30/01/2015) it gives correct result but when I change start date & end date as 01/02/2015 & 28/02/2015 then it shows the records including Jan month.

sql = "Select [Working_Date] From Attendance where [Working_Date] BETWEEN#" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "#AND#" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date + " #";

4. As per my understanding there is some problem with Formatting of Dates but still i couldn't figure  this out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, I got the solution, there was the problem with Formatting of dates.

I used following query with Medium date formatting in Ms access.

```
sql = "Select User_Name,Shift,Format(Working_Date,'dd-MMM-yyyy') as
Working_Date,In_Time,Out_Time,Attendance,Working_Hrs,Department From Attendance
where [User_Name]=('" + Login_Frm.User_Name + "') AND [Department]=('" + 
Dpt_ID.Text + "') AND Working_Date BETWEEN#" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "#AND#" + 
dateTimePicker2.Text +"# ORDER BY [EMP_ID]";
```

Thanks for your great help